# Add CSS Class to certain text inputs that have an onclick value

Tags: jquery, css

I have some text inputs that have onclick functions

i want to be able to assign a CSS class to these text inputs that have a certain onclick function

i tried using this in JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').each(function() {
       if($(this).find("onclick:datetime_picker").val() == "") {
            $(this).addClass("DateTimePickerInput");
       }
    });
});
```

but that didnt work

Comment: There's no way to do that, you can select elements by attributes, as in `$('[onclick="datetime_picker()"]')` but that matches the exact text of the attribute, and has nothing to do with the function really.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').each(function() {
        if ($._data(this, 'events')['click:datetime_picker']) {
            $(this).addClass('DateTimePickerInput');
        }
    });
});
```

**Edit:**

Try this instead:

```
$('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is('[onclick^=datetime_picker()]')) {
        $(this).addClass('DateTimePickerInput');
    }
});
```

Comment: Aha, yes, that solution won't work. I assumed you had implemented it in a different way. I'll edit the answer with a new solution that'll work.